# How to add existing item from another model as a M2M field through patch request?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, patch, serialization

I'm trying to add an existing or new item from MenuItem model to ItemCategory model which are linked using ManyToMany field. If MenuItem object doesn't exists in database, it works well, but existing MenuItem cannot be added, it says something like menu_item already exists.

> View

```py
class ItemCategoryView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """Update, Edit or delete ItemCategory objects"""
    serializer_class = ItemCategorySerializer
    queryset = ItemCategory.objects.all()

    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        return self.retrieve(request)

    def put(self, request, id=None):
        return self.update(request, id)

    def delete(self, request, id):
        return self.destroy(request, id)
```

> Serializer

```py
class ItemCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for ItemCategory objects"""
    item = MenuItemSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ItemCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'item')
        read_only_fields = ('id', )

    # Creating with nested serializer
    def create(self, validated_data):
        menu_item = validated_data.pop('item', None)
        category = ItemCategory.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # if list of menu item info is passed
        if menu_item:
            items = []
            for item in menu_item:
                itm = MenuItem.objects.create(**item)
                items.append(itm)

            category.item.add(*items)
        return category

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Works perfectly in case if item doesn't exists"""
        new_items = validated_data.pop('item')
        items_to_be_added_to_category = []

        for new_item in new_items:
            try:
                item_obj = MenuItem.objects.get(**new_item)
            except MenuItem.DoesNotExist:
                item_obj = MenuItem.objects.create(**new_item)
            items_to_be_added_to_category.append(item_obj)

        instance.item.add(*items_to_be_added_to_category)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

> Failed TestCase

```py
    def test_add_existing_item_to_category(self):
        """Test adding existing item object to category"""
        category_obj = sample_category("Mutton Special")
        item_obj, item_obj_info = sample_item(
                                              item_name="Mutton Sekuwa",
                                              payload_only=False
                                             )
        payload = {
            "name": category_obj.name,
            "item": [item_obj_info]
        }
        res = self.client.patch(
            reverse(UPDATE_ITEM_CATEGORY_URL, kwargs={'id': category_obj.id}),
            payload,
            format="json"
        )

        category_obj = ItemCategory.objects.get(id=category_obj.id)
        category_item = category_obj.item.all()
        serializer = ItemCategorySerializer(category_obj)


        self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
        self.assertIn(item_obj, category_item)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_existing_item_to_category (Menu.tests.test_category_api.ItemCategoryAPITest)
Test adding existing item object to category
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/rms/Menu/tests/test_category_api.py", line 117, in test_add_existing_item_to_category
    self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
AssertionError: {'item': [{'item_name': [ErrorDetail(string=[62 chars])]}]} != {'id': 2, 'name': 'Mutton Special', 'item': 
[]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the validation of the item in ItemCategorySerializer which is not allowing to add existing item.

So i created a seprate serializer for MenuItem by escaping it's validation and introduced new field called action on MenuItemSerializer which can be used to delete/remove the specific model object from the same api endpoint.

```py
class NestedMenuItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for updating item objects in ItemCategory"""
    ACTION_CHOICE = (
        ('remove', 'remove'),
        ('delete', 'delete')
    )

    action = serializers.ChoiceField(
        choices=ACTION_CHOICE,
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = (
            'id',
            'item_name',
            'price',
            'description',
            'item_type',
            'image',
            'action'
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'item_name': {'validators': []}, # escaping validation
            'action': {'validators': []}
        }
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'url')

class UpdateItemCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Creating ItemCategory objects"""
    item = NestedMenuItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ItemCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'item')
        read_only_fields = ('id', )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        items_info = validated_data.pop('item')

        for item_info in items_info:
            action = item_info.pop('action', None)
            if action:
                item_obj = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, **item_info)
                if action is "remove":
                    instance.item.remove(item_obj)
                elif action is "delete":
                    item_obj.delete()
            else:
                item_name = item_info.pop('item_name', None)
                item_obj, _ = MenuItem.objects.get_or_create(
                    item_name=item_name,
                    defaults=item_info
                )
                instance.item.add(item_obj)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```